# Configured mailman but can't browse to index page from a different machine

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos-6, mailman

Hi, I configured mail man on a server and it says got to page

```
http://server1/mailman/
```

It works locally on the server; but can access that page from a different machine; it fails;

-> I am using Cent OS 6 and mailman
-> Do i need to open any http access ports? I though outgoing port 80 is open by default.

Please do let me know if any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out its a firewall issue, stopping IPtables fixed it.